# Displaying adjacent lists in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a menu for a restaurant on their webpage. I am trying to make 2 adjacent lists. I have successfully done so but there is a huge amount of space between each list item. Also, the accents on the words do not show up properly in the webpage. Any thoughts? Here is my code:

```css
#list {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#list li {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#list2 {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  float: right;
}

#list2 li {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li><dt><b>1 Chả Giò Chay</b></dt><dd>Vegetarian Spring Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>
  <li><dt><b>2 Chả Giò</b></dt><dd>Spring Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>
  <li><dt><b>3 Gỏi Cuốn Chay</b></dt><dd>Fresh rice paper Vegetarian Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>
  <li><dt><b>4 Gỏi Cuốn</b></dt><dd>Fresh rice paper Shrimp & Pork Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>
  <li><dt><b>5 Gỏi Cuốn Thịt</b></dt><dd>Fresh rice paper Pork Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
  <li><dt><b>11 Gà Chiên Bột</b></dt><dd>Spring Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>
  <li><dt><b>12 Gà Teriyaki</b></dt><dd>Spring Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>
  <li><dt><b>13 Gà Đặc Biệt</b></dt><dd>Spring Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>
  <li><dt><b>14 Ca Chiên</b></dt><dd>Spring Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>
  <li><dt><b>15 Ca Viên Chiên</b></dt><dd>Spring Rolls(2)</dd><br></li>                   
</ul>
```

Comment: What question are you asking?  It seems you have two... Something to do with the undesirable space, and the other, regarding accents. See here: [How to ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: (There are character references for "Latin characters with diacritics", e.g. `&eacute;`.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for your lists you added `<br>` tags. I don't think that these are necessary. Without them I don't get any exaggerated space in between lines.

As for your other question, you will want to look into a couple of options:

1. meta charset characters. you should be able to use the unicode 8; add the following to the header of your page if you haven't already! `<meta charset="utf-8">`
2. Substitute the characters out for special HTML entities (not recommended and rather inefficient. http://art-hanoi.com/vncode/

Answer (score 0):

use the margin property for the lists to set the spacing between elements.